# Add additional data to paginated resource laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is the response of a GET request in an API with paginated data:

```
{
"current_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "user_id": 1,
        "text": "kek",
        "path": "public/gifs/mfNEs0XOK7X3ovIYdMwW67lemI4oRAos0ufxNeBm.gif",
        "created_at": "2020-09-18T01:32:47.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-18T01:32:47.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "user_id": 1,
        "text": "kek",
        "path": "public/gifs/bFwa5My7NlkdtTFiqn6FXLzpcbaL9703phDEYQ5i.gif",
        "created_at": "2020-09-18T01:38:55.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-18T01:38:55.000000Z"
    }
],
// ... rest of the pagination data
}
```

I need to insert a `tags` field in each of the models, which values comes from a Many To Many relationship.

Do I need to iterate the collection and insert each value manually or does laravel have a built in method for that?

Current function:

```
public function index()
{
    $expressions = $this->expression->paginate(20);
    
    return response()->json($expressions);
}
```

Comment: do you have a relationship setup from Expression to Tag?

Comment: Yes, the data I want to add is from `$expression->tags();` which is a many to many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the relationship so it is part of the serialized output of the Model:

```
$expressions = $this->expression->with('tags')->paginate(20);
```

Assuming `$this->expression` is an instance of your Model.

> "When an Eloquent model is converted to JSON, its loaded relationships will automatically be included as attributes on the JSON object."

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Serialization - Serializing to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with`